# Are these circles in the exposed pad of a VQFN footprint meant to be non-metallized, and if so, for what purpose?

Tags: footprint, pad

I am creating a footprint for a TI [TXS0108ERGYR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf?ts=1677778008883&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTXS0108E) level shifter and encountered these circles drawn in the exposed pad for its land pattern:

[image: Land pattern example]

Are these meant to be non-metallized and if so, for what purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic case of not reading one keyword: "via." The callout specifies Ø0.2 mm diameter typical ***via***.

The solder paste example (on the next page) shows these vias in between solder paste deposits, presumably to help avoid solder being wicked into the via thereby not requiring plugged vias.